# How to get count of messages in inbox folder including child folders for a particular period of time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Here is what I tried:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?filter=ReceivedDateTime+gt+2018-12-06T06:13:00Z+and+ReceivedDateTime+lt+2018-12-07T20:13:00Z&%24count=true`

But the above query only returns a count of messages from Inbox. It doesn't include any subfolders.

Is there a way to query to include subfolders as well in the above query?

Comment: Have you checked this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 3):

You will have to write a recursive function and call the above query for each child folder under Inbox.

You can get child folder under inbox using:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/childfolders
```

You can then run this for each folder:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/childfolders/{childFolderID}/messages?filter=ReceivedDateTime+gt+2018-12-06T06:13:00Z+and+ReceivedDateTime+lt+2018-12-13T20:13:00Z&%24count=true`

Comment: Thank you, I thought there would be an easy option to include sub folders in the query.